# Mod rewrite string query from old website page to new

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been struggling with this for several weeks and cannot get it!
I have several old pages (thousands) that have a string like below(we moved shopping carts)

www.example.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=86895 AND

www.example.com/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&search=action&searchstart=20&keywords=blahblah

I would like to redirect these pages to a search page on my new site.  I have used the following but it does not work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/commerce.cgi\?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/newpage? [R=301,L]
```

Please help me so I can go back to growing my hair!

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. your condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$` means that the query string is empty. You are actually trying to redirect whether the query string is empty or not.
2. your rule looks for a `?` in the url, but the query string is not part of the text that can be matched in a rule.

Use this shorter rule, without a RewriteCond (tested on Apache 2.4):

```
RewriteRule ^/?cgi-bin/commerce\.cgi http://www.example.com/newpage? [R=301,L]
```

Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Well explained solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting following in htaccess file

```
# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
Redirect 301 / http://newwebsiteurl.com/
```